# Does it make sense to use Vuejs and Reactjs on the same project

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

So my question is pretty self explanatory. Does it make sense to use Vue.js and React.js together on a same project ?

Comment: You need to give more background. Do you have a lot of existing code in one of the two and are considering adding new code in the other? If so, what made you unhappy about the existing framework? Is there a specific component that you must absolutely have that is only available for one framework? How big is the team?

Comment: @Thilo I'm just trying to know if It is possible to combine both of them into a same project. There is some features I like in vue.js and others I like in React, But ultimately , both are doing the same work , so I will choose one and stick with it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. Both Vue.js and React are for the same purpose - building UI components.

The only situation that it *might* make sense is that if you are doing a migration. From Vue.js to React or from React to Vue.js.

But I think in most scenarios it doesn't worth to do this kind of migration. Both Vue.js and React are really great. So my conclusion is, no, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Both Vue and Reactjs are javascript Frameworks that are in themselves self sufficient. Also since both do the same job it makes sense to use either one of them.

If you use both Vue and React together it will make it more and more difficult for you to share states and data between parts written with Vue and Parts written with React.

What you would have to do is to keep them as independent modules.

Also both Vue and ReactJs have different APIs so it makes it difficult for a developer to code it out too. This will lead to bad patterns and hacks developing in your code which will later lead to issues such as maintainability and feature extension.

If you have control over your entire code, its better to just evaluate what better suits your purpose and then choose that framework for development of the entire app.

**P.S.** Certains exceptions to using both of them together will include a migration from framework to another in progress or your app having various modules in your App each of which independent from one another and included as plugins in the main code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the two together but you will have to carefully consider the architecture. You might have to consider something like the Microfrontend architecture but remember this comes at the cost of a lot of complexity and is not suited for all use cases.

[Good intro to Micro Frontends](https://micro-frontends.org/)